# C# Selenium Visual Studio stopped finding elements with no locator, the same tests once passed now give them an error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver, findelement

I'm a beginner and I'm learning automated testing, but I have a problem with Visual Studio 2022, it doesn't find elements with FindElement with any locator. Тhe first tests of the project pass, and it found elements with FindElement, but on the lower lines it started to show an error and does not locate elements. And of two projects in Solution, one passes the same tests and the other shows an error.

I read similar problems and tried this but no change

```bash
Driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
Thread.Sleep(2000);
```

If anyone had the same problem as mine ...

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [repro] (which should include a representative sample of the HTML you are dealing with). Currently, we do not have enough information to provide an answer.